# If el contains this text, remove this string from it?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am trying to check if the clicked item contains a certain text and if so remove it.

```
<ul class="filter option-set dropdown-menu" role="menu" aria-labelledby="dropdownMenu1" data-filter-group="Agencies">
  <li><a class="btn btn-default btn-lg" href="#filter-client-any" data-filter-value="">All agencies</a></li>

  <li><a id="filter-a" class="btn btn-default btn-lg" href="#filter-agency-a" data-filter-value=".A">A</a></li>
  <li><a id="filter-z" class="btn btn-default btn-lg" href="#filter-agency-z" data-filter-value=".Z">Z</a></li>
  <li><a id="filter-c" class="btn btn-default btn-lg" href="#filter-agency-c" data-filter-value=".c">C</a></li>
  <li><a id="filter-h" class="btn btn-default btn-lg" href="#filter-agency-h" data-filter-value=".h">H</a></li>
</ul>

$(document).on( 'click touchend', '.filter a', function( event ) {
  event.preventDefault();
  var self = $(this);
  if(self.html().indexOf("All ")!=-1)
  self.html(self.html().replace("All ", ""));
});
```

The above code gives me: `Uncaught TypeError: undefined is not a function`

Comment: Never *ever* use `.html()` to manipulate DOM elements - it converts the elements to text and then back to nodes, destroying any other changes or event handlers registered on those nodes.  It's OK for creating new elements, though.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to replace the text.

Try this.

```
$("a").on("click", function(){
    var self = $(this);
    if(self.html().indexOf("All")!=-1)
    self.html(self.html().replace("All", ""));
});
```

Or you can go with `$("a:contains('All')")` selector.

```
$("a:contains('All')").on("click", function(){
    var self = $(this);
    self.html(self.html().replace("All", ""));
});
```

Comment: i still need to check if it has it or not

Comment: Why do you need to check it, It will replace it if it has it else it wont throw an error.

Comment: See the question with my updated full code, your answer is still giving me Uncaught TypeError: undefined is not a function

Comment: I guess it is working fine... http://jsfiddle.net/voidSO/fgm9ndp8/ .. Are you including jQuery?

Comment: When i click on `All agencies` it replace it to `agencies`.

Comment: i must have something on my side because your code makes sense but i still get the same error

Comment: Yes exactly, You saw the fiddle? If it solves your problem please consider voting it up and marking it as correct answer.

Comment: yes but i am not targeting all tags "a" as you can see in my question code. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

You need to actually *set* the new text content, beside that your condition to check for existing string might not work like that.

```
if( $(this).text().indexOf('All ') > -1 ) {
    $(this).text(function(_, text) {
        return text.replace(/All\s+/g, '');
    });
}
```

Comment: is it still within the if?

Answer (score 1):

> [**jQuery.contains()**](http://api.jquery.com/jquery.contains/) is used to Check to see if a DOM element is a descendant of another DOM element.

you have to use native `match()` or any other way. Try this one.

```
<a href="#">All works</a>
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function() {
    $("a").on("click", function() {
        if ($(this).text().match("All ").index != -1) {
            $(this).text($(this).text().replace(/All /g, ''));
        }
    });
});
</script>
```

**Snippet**

```js
 $(document).on('click touchend', '.filter a', function(event) {
  var self = $(this);
  if (self.html().indexOf("All ") != -1)
   self.html(self.html().replace("All ", ""));
 });
```

```html
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
 <script type="text/javascript" src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-2.1.3.min.js"></script>
 <script>
 </script>
</head>

<body>
 <ul class="filter option-set dropdown-menu" role="menu" aria-labelledby="dropdownMenu1" data-filter-group="Agencies">
  <li>
   <a class="btn btn-default btn-lg" href="#filter-client-any" data-filter-value="">All agencies</a>
  </li>

  <li><a id="filter-a" class="btn btn-default btn-lg" href="#filter-agency-a" data-filter-value=".A">A</a>
  </li>
  <li><a id="filter-z" class="btn btn-default btn-lg" href="#filter-agency-z" data-filter-value=".Z">Z</a>
  </li>
  <li><a id="filter-c" class="btn btn-default btn-lg" href="#filter-agency-c" data-filter-value=".c">C</a>
  </li>
  <li><a id="filter-h" class="btn btn-default btn-lg" href="#filter-agency-h" data-filter-value=".h">H</a>
  </li>
 </ul>

 
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: See updated question with full code, you answer when applied gives me:  Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'index' of null

Comment: yes I can see it working and by reading your code i could already see that was right, therefore i must have something else as it is still giving me the error on my side tho

Comment: guess what? I had to place the code before the event.preventDefault(), I am not sure why

Answer (score 0):

This works for me:

```
$(document).on( 'click touchend', '.filter a', function( event ) {
  var self = $(this);
  if (self.text().indexOf("All ") > -1) {
    self.text(self.text().replace("All ", ""));
  }
});
```

Note that I am using .text(), not .html().